# Using '\' in javascript to declare string occupying multiple lines

Tags: javascript, syntax

While looking through a 3rd party JavaScript API and example code I noticed the following declaration. Basically XML assigned to a string but they seem to split it up on multiple lines using '\', I was unaware this could be done in javascript. Could anyone provide some more details on how this works?

Thanks.

```
var PrimaryChannel = '<ChannelParams ChannelType="Digital"> \
                                <DigitalChannelParams \
                                    PhysicalChannelIDType="Cable" \
                                    PhysicalChannelID="107" \
                                    DemodMode="QAM256" \
                                    ProgramSelectionMode="PATProgram" \
                                    ProgramID="2"> \
                                </DigitalChannelParams> \
                            </ChannelParams>';
```

Comment: That looks funny because the backslashes are inside the quotes... which makes me believe that it isn't really a JS thing and those slashes are either being preserved in the string, or... they're escaping the newline.

Comment: @Mark, they ARE escaping the newline

Comment: @Chad: Yeah.. but I mean, it's not the same thing as closing the quote, and *then* escaping the newline, is it? In one case you're just telling JS that the line continues so it shouldn't work is magic-semi-colon BS, and in the other case, you're saying what should be included in the string, no? Or maybe I'm confusing languages and how they handle these things... Python for instance lets you butt two strings up next to each other and it'll just join em for you.

Comment: @Chad: Here's what I mean: http://pastebin.com/kW7CvjMc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is escaping the newline character, but it's not recommended.  If you minify your js after the fact, it will break horribly.

You are better off doing something like

```
var myString = 
   ['line1',
    'line2',
    'line3',
    'line4',
    'line5'].join('\n');
```

or

```
var mystring = 
    'line1' + 
    'line2' + 
    'line3' + 
    'line4' + 
    'line5';
```

Answer (score 2):

most browsers support this. it's not standards-compliant however

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. `\` is the line continuation character in JavaScript.

Edit: It's technically an escape character.